# Bootstrap customizing button style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization

I want to change style of Bootstrap buttons so it doesn't have the default look.
I can easily change the color from their [customization](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) page but what I want to do is removing the gradient value so it looks flat.

I can see there are a few other approaches to do this and what I've done is creating my own custom.css for overwriting styles of any Bootstrap elements and have it linked below default bootstrap css within the html. 
I have my custom styles over `.btn .btn-success` for customizing green button as documented [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) but it doesn't do anything.

I basically would like to know the correct steps of overwriting default styles
in the context of customizing buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On bootstrap .css , find all styles for btn-primary and copy them to your custom .css.

Now change the name to the color as you want .btn-primary = .btn-blue

And then, delete or change the elements.

In your button use the class you created:

```
<button class="btn btn-customcollor">Custom Button</button>
```

Example for gray button:

```
.btn.btn-gray {
    border: 1px solid #626e7f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #9aa4b1;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #9aa4b1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #9aa4b1;
    background: #758294;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjUwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iNTAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzhjOTdhNiIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzc1ODI5NCIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #8c97a6), color-stop(100%, #758294));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #758294);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #758294);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #758294);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #758294); 
}


.btn.btn-gray:hover {
    background: #728092;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjUwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iNTAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzhjOTdhNiIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzcyODA5MiIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #8c97a6), color-stop(100%, #728092));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #728092);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #728092);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #728092);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #8c97a6, #728092);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.05s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.05s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.05s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow 0.05s ease-in-out; 
}


.btn.btn-gray:active {
    background: #818d9d;
    border-color: #5d6979;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #818d9d inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #818d9d inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #818d9d inset; 
}

.btn-group.open .btn.btn-gray.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: #8c97a6; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written about the workaround for this problem here. A simple way to stylize the bootstrap buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960203/3167046