# How to put back the hover effect on Bootstrap3's buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The devs said Bootstrap 3 would come bundled with an optional theme to make it look like Bootstrap 2.

The problem is they seem to have forgotten to put the hover effects on the buttons. Is there a way to put that back?

This is how it looks on v2, just move the mouse over any button and see the effect:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html

And this is how it looks now in v3 (no effect):

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create your own custom class, say, `.btn-custom`, and then apply your preferred styling, including hover effect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128904/styling-twitters-bootstrap-3-x-buttons) shows you how to create your own button styles in Boostrap 3.

This website also helps to easily generate the CSS styles: http://twitterbootstrap3buttons.w3masters.nl